# Magento Security Tool False Positive? prototype.js identified as compromise injection

Tags: security-scan-tool

Is anyone else having issues with Magento Security Tool Scanner?
https://account.magento.com/scanner/

Your site is compromised with injected JavaScript. (79)
The malicious code signature(s) has been found in resources:

```
/js/prototype/prototype.js
/js/prototype/validation.js
/js/scriptaculous/controls.js
```

I am getting this scan failure on 12 different magento sites so it must be a false positive.  Yesterday all sites were passing the scanner.  Today they all say they are compromised injected with malware.

All warnings on all sites are pointing to prototype.js

Comment: Having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run head against the files and tail and see if you have any base64 etc at the top or bottom. Don’t just edit in nano or something. It might be a false positive but most likely will be revealed by head command or tail.